# Defining an NFC tag as NDEF using the Arduino Uno and the PN532 NFC module

Tags: arduino-uno, rfid

I bought a bunch of blank Mifare Classic NFC cards and I'd like to write NDEF records to them using my Arduino Uno. When I read them using my Uno and a PN532 NFC module using [Don's NDEF library](https://github.com/don/NDEF/blob/master/examples/ReadTagExtended/ReadTagExtended.ino) however, it tells me they're not NDEF formatted.

Is there any way to define my NFC tags as NDEF using just the PN532 module and an Arduino Uno? (My Android phone doesn't support NFC.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question right after posting it, while going through the examples included in the library above:

The library contains an example named "FormatTag" which does exactly what I was looking for.